# How to pass multiple parameters in .htaccess file in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have URL that I want to redirect 301 .
The old URL should redirect to new URL.

Example -
`https://www.dummy.com/service-centers/Rajasthan/Kekri/Riico-Industrial-Area/Riico-Industrial-Area--Shoes-Factory/Ekam-Motors/370`  - old URL

`https://www.dummy.com/service-centers/Kekri/Ekam-Motors/370` - new URL

I have been trying to get this done using below .htaccess but I end up getting this

```
redirect 301 /service-centers/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1  /car-service-centers/$3/$6/$1
```

but its not working please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The first argument should be a regex expression, something like this should do it.

```
redirect 301 /service-centers/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9A-Za-z-_]+)  /car-service-centers/$2/$5/$6
```

Comment: its not redirecting on new URL